# Load JSON with AJAX to be used in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I've got two functions, one is called as soon as a button is triggered, the other one when the "process" triggered by the button is finished.
I would like to to load the JSON data from the AJAX request in the `calculatePrize()` function to reduce loading time at the end of function `Finish()`

```
function calculatePrize() {
    // ...some code goes here
    // I would like to load the AJAX data already here and just parse it in the "finish Function"
}

function Finish() {
    // retrieve win
    $.getJSON("/generate").done(function(data){
        // console.log(data.state)
        // set the win amount
        amount_field.append( document.createTextNode(data.win_amount));
    });
}
```

How to do so in the best way?

Comment: Use Nested Ajax for this approach

Comment: It's hard to help you as you've not given enough code, but a general idea would be to do the work required in `calculatePrize()` and make the AJAX request, storing the result in a variable accessible to both functions, along with a flag to state the request has completed. Then you can use that data when the `Finish()` function is called.

Comment: I just need to load AJAX call in the first function and store result in a var. After this I just need to be able to call this var in the last function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call the `calculatePrize` function from the Ajax Done - and pass the data as parameter

```
function calculatePrize(responsData) {
     console.log(responseData);
}

function Finish() {
    // retrieve win
    $.getJSON("/generate").done(function(data){

       // Call the function - pass the data as parameter
       calculatePrize(data);

    });
}
```

OR

store the data in a global variable and access in the `calculatePrize` function

```
    var responseData = null;

    function calculatePrize() {
         console.log(responseData);
    }

    function Finish() {
        // retrieve win
        $.getJSON("/generate").done(function(data){

           responseData = data;

           // Call the function 
           calculatePrize();

        });
    }
```